# Copying & Pasting inverted image in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency, background, mask

I have a basic image that is black on a white background.  I simply want to invert the image, take the now white portion and paste it on another image in GIMP.  I am having no luck.

[image: bird]

Within GIMP, I open that bird and I also open my background to be pasted upon.

On the bird, I click on Colors/Invert and now the portion I want to keep is white.

[image: inverted bird]

Now, I don't know what to do.  I've tried various layers/masks but don't really understand and cannot seem to get just the white portion on to my second image.  I can cut and paste the whole thing but I don't want the black background.  I think what I want is just the transparency or whatever the white portion is.

Is there a simple way to do this?  Any clear-cut steps?

Comment: could you mark my answer as the answer, so this question can be closed? thanks!

Comment: Important to note that you don't mean *closed* as in closed as duplicate or such, right?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to remove one color is:

- Colors > color to alpha
- select black (HTML: 000000)
- ok > ok
- done

[image]

Then you can copy-paste the layer onto any other image.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: No Problem, although I think you could've found this by using Google

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively - you can just use the `Select by color` tool (just next to the magic wand on the tool box) - and click on any white part of the image. This will select the white areas - then, just copy and paste on the target image.

The "color to alpha" as @PieBie put it, is more precise, and better to remove a solid background when you want to keep a lot of other colors - but for a simpler case like this, the `select by color` can easily pick all you want to carry to over.